# In-App Purchase Programming - iPhone - Can this unlock content on my web site community too?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am in a development team debating whether we should process subscriptions for premium content

1) on our online community web site or

2) in our iPhone app via the In-app purchase feature.

The question we still have is:

If a member of our online site (registered member) downloads the iPhone app (as another way to interact with our online content) and decides to purchase the "Premium" features via the iPhone in-app purchase feature (unlocking new content on the iPhone app)

Can our servers then **know** that this member has upgraded via the app and in response unlock content on our web site, too?

Answer (score 1):

The store sends the app a message whenever a user makes an in app purchase, so your app could react to the message by sending a message to your server. The question I would have is whether the contract with Apple would permit this, particularly if the user could buy the content on the web site without paying Apple and then access it through the app.

Comment: I feel confident about Apple's allowance of subscription outside of the app. Here is a relevant stackoverflow.com thread about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435656/licensing-iphone-apps-per-user-in-existing-system  However, I do  not know for sure that Apple allows you to unlock content on your own website based on the in-app purchase feature.